# How to customise the background of Wordpress login page?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Intended Results: Add a custom css to customize the Wordpress login page background.

**Steps Taken:**

Created a new folder in my theme folder called Login. In this, made a new custom css file called custom-login-style.css.

Added a code to the functions.php, that tells Wordpress to load the custom-login-style.css found in the Login folder.

```
function my_custom_login()
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/login/custom-login-style.css" />';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');
```

The CSS is working fine but has only customized the login form.

> Issue: I am not able to customize the background of the login page.

For the page background I have added the following css

```
body.login {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0b4182 1%, #1e88e5 100%) fixed;
 }

body, html {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0b4182 1%, #1e88e5 100%) fixed;
}
```

CSS for the background is not working but the css meant for the login form is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there might have been an issue with the functions.php code, so I researced a bit and followed the customization as recommended by the Wordpress Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Changed

```
function my_custom_login()
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/login/custom-login-style.css" />';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');
```

to that found in codex:

```
function my_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/login/custom-login-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_stylesheet' );
```

and `body .login` css started working and the background got customised. I am unsure why  and what exactly resolved the issue, it may be due to enqueing the stylesheet or may be something else. One thing, its always better to research and implement the Codex in case of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the link to that page.
Most likely you have some CSS problems.
You can open Chrome inspector and watch what is the result css for your login page.
May be `!important` is used somewhere and your css is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use inline style to make sure it will override the default style:

```php
function my_custom_login() { 
    ?>
    <style>
        /* Body style */
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0b4182 1%, #1e88e5 100%) fixed;
        }
        /* Logo style */
        .login h1 a {
          ...
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');
```